# How to get a module which send's IRP request

Tags: c, module, kernel, driver, irp

I have a kernel driver. My dll inside process(injected dll) send IRP request to this driver. How this driver could get this module handle?
Something like `IoGetRequestorProcess(Irp)` but module handle instead of process.

Comment: @KeithMiller nothing, i didn't find something about it.

Comment: Don't think you will able to find out which function (dll API) sent an IRP.

Answer (score -1):

u can try some kernel APIs,just like `IoGetRequestorProcess` or `IoGetRequestorProcessId`